# Import Javascript into CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```css
div
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div::after
{
position: inline-block;
  content: "Something";
 }
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Hi is it possible to import a JS function into CSS?

Say I have a JS function

```
funtion mytitle()
{
return "Something";
}
```

Is it possible to insert this funtion into CSS' content instead of hard coding it like i did in the snippet? I mean something like

```
div::after
{ content: mytitle();
}
```

Comment: Short answer: No. Some CSS preprocessors allow logic, and CSS has some basic functions, but vanilla CSS will never allow JS execution like this.

Comment: since you tagged react, just make it a component.

Comment: If you want to do something like this using pure CSS/JS then you could set the content to a CSS variable and change that variable using your JS function.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this.
You must use preprocessors to pass variable/functions to styles.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, you cannot import a JavaScript function to CSS

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do it in opposite way - instead of importing JavaScript into CSS, you can change CSS via JavaScript.

But you want to modify a psuedo element, which JavaScript can not do. So you can write CSS to the document to override the previous CSS.

Please note that it is not recommended to write CSS to document, instead you should change your approach, like adding another element instead of a psuedo element. The following is just for reference of how you can do it via JavaScript.

```js
function changeCSS() {
  document.documentElement.innerHTML += '<style>div::after{content: "asdf";}</style>';
}
```

```css
div
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div::after
{
position: inline-block;
  content: "Something";
 }
```

```html
<div>

</div>
<button onclick="changeCSS();" type="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no syntax where the CSS calls out to the JS.

You can use a `<script>` element to load JS into an HTML document, then that JS can [access the document's stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) and modify them.

```js
Array.from(document.styleSheets).forEach(css => {
  Array.from(css.cssRules).forEach(rule => {
    if (rule.selectorText === "div::after") {
      rule.style.setProperty('content', '"foo"');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div::after {
  position: inline-block;
  content: "Something";
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Note that it is `'"foo"'` not `"foo"` because the CSS value needs the quotes in it.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't do it but we can accomplish the same result using [Lesscss](https://lesscss.org/functions/#functions-overview)
where we can use some built-in function but we can't write our own.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, but there is a work around to achieve this goal. By using **attributes** to Show **::after** content in element.

In below **HTML** code we are using **data-content** attribute, where we show are content return value from our jQuery method.

```
<div data-content=""></div>
```

In CSS replace content static `content: "Something";` value to dynamic attribute value `content: attr(data-content);`.

```
div::after {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

Now, just write a simple jQuery method for returning value in `data-content` attribute.

```
function mytitle() {
  $('div').attr("data-content", "Something change");
}

mytitle();
```

All above mentioned changes are already implemented in below code snippet. I hope it'll help you out. Thank You

```js
function mytitle() {
  $('div').attr("data-content", "Something change");
}

mytitle();
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div::after {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-content=""></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for this. Created a snipped where I just update the text of the second element via JS. You can do this for how many elements you like.

```js
function mytitle() {
  document.querySelector('.demo').style.setProperty('--some-text', '"My 2nd Value"');
}

mytitle();
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  --some-text: 'Hello World';
  margin: 10px 0;
}

div::after {
  position: inline-block;
  content: var(--some-text);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>

<div class="demo">

</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it with additional Javascript and `document.querySelector()`

For example,

```
<div id="title">
</div>

function myTitle(){
    element = document.querySelector('#title')
    element.innerHTML = "Something"
}
```